# Silverlight grid with a large number of rows and columns

Tags: xaml, grid

I would like to know what is the recommended way of designing a Silverlight page with many controls in it, like a lob application for example. What I think would be simpler, especially if there are many pages to make, is to make a template page with a large number of rows and columns of the same dimension, so that I can visually put every control into the grid. In this way, each control will have something like absolute coordinates, as well as rowspan and columnspan.

Isn't this one the easiest way to design? I think such a layout would also be easier to modify, since if I want to move a textbox from the left to the right side of the screen, I only have to change it's Grid.Column property, without minding all the interactions with the stackpanels and the grids on the right side, like I see in many layouts that are organized with a number of grids and stackpanels.

And can the fact of having a large number of rows and columns decrease the performances?

Thanks for any opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Canvas control if you want to do absolute positioning.

Comment: I don't want to do absolute positioning, but to use a grid, it is more flexible (for example if I increase the fonts I don't risk to overlap the texts).

Comment: well, by all means the grid is very powerful and probably the easiest way to do layout. in reality you'll never have a form with more than 10-15 rows and not even that much columns so the performance is a no issue.

Comment: you are welcome... I've been wondering about the same thing (layout for very large forms with 200+ fields) for ever... a vertical stack panel of horizontal stack panels seems to work best for me...